# On primes that are a sum of two Fibonacci numbers

Tags: prime-numbers, fibonacci-numbers

This question is about primes that are sums of two Fibonacci numbers.

$$
\begin{align}
2 &= 1 + 1 \\
3 &= 1 + 2 \\
5 &= 2 + 3 \\
7 &= 2 + 5 \\
11 &= 3 + 8 \\
13 &= 5 + 8 \\
&\mathbf{17 = ?} \\
&\mathbf{19 = ?} \\
23 &= 2 + 21 \\
29 &= 8 + 21 \\
31 &= 34 + (-1) \\
   &= \text{$F_9 + F_{-4}$} \\
37 &= 3 + 34 \\
&\mathbf{41 = ?} \\
\cdots
\end{align}
$$

**Decompositions $a+b$ for $17$:**

$$
\begin{smallmatrix}
a &0 &1 &2 &3 &4 &5 &6 &7 &8 &9 &10 &11 &12 &13 &14 &15 &16 &17 \\
b &17 &16 &15 &14 &13 &12 &11 &10 &9 &8 &7 &6 &5 &4 &3 &2 &1 &0 \\
\hline                 
a &0 &-1 &-2 &-3 &-4 &-5 &-6 &-7 &-8 &-9 &-10 &-11 &-12 &-13 &-14 &-15 &-16 &-17 \\
b &17 &18 &19 &20 &21 &22 &23 &24 &25 &26 &27 &28 &29 &30 &31 &32 &33 &34 \\
\end{smallmatrix}
$$

So, obviously there are primes that don't have that representation.

**Question:** Can we characterize the primes that do have a representation $p = F_a + F_b$ where $a,b \in \mathbb{Z}$ and the Fibonacci series $\{F_k\}$ is extended with $k$ going to negative integers as well.

Comment: If we go to larger primes, primes with such a representation will become extremely rare.

Comment: $1$ is not a prime number.

Comment: @Stahl: You are right. The modern definition of primes excludes $1$. I've edited. 

The question was motivated by thinking about $N \in \mathbb{Z}$ where $N = F_a + F_b$. I then thought of restricting to primes and semiprimes by formulating a multiplication composition rule involving primes of the form. It was convenient to add $1$ along with the primes although my main question now deals with primes. Hope that context helps.

Comment: I think that $1$ is not considered to be prime since a long time. There are very good reasons to exclude $1$

Comment: $11$ is a Fibonacci number?

Comment: Primes that are the sum of two *positive* Fibonacci numbers are tabulated at https://oeis.org/A178576

Comment: @Gerry: $11$ is a prime that is $8 + 3$ which are Fibonacci numbers. Thanks for the OEIS sequence. Also, I had made an error including $19 = 11 + 8$ as the Fibonacci decomposition. 11 isn't in $\{F_k\}$. Question has been edited.

Comment: According to my calculations , only $69$ out of the first $10^7$ primes have such a representation.